# How to dump a .net core 2.0 console application in Linux Docker's container?

Tags: .net, docker, dump

I have an .net core 2.0 console application running in a Linux docker's container,
some keys env as below:

1.docker base image:**FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime**

2.Linux version:centos 7.2

Now, I want to investigate some problems, so I need to dump **in the docker inside**

Ps:the .net core application in the docker container is running all the time, and **not crash**